# PyQt4 script frozen by PyInstaller gives Fatal Error:"Failed to execute script xyz"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, fatal-error, pyinstaller

I am writing the following Python 3.5 script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("HelloGUI")
        self.show()


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

I create executable using PyInstaller. It runs normally. Though when I try to run the executable on a different PC (which has no Python installed) than mine, it gives the following Fatal Error Message: "Failed to execute script [script-name]".

If someone has an idea how I can make my GUI programms portable, please leave a comment. Otherwise, if what I have in my mind cannot be done, please let me know.

---

Windows10 (64 bit), Python 3.5(32 bit), PyInstaller(3.2), PyQt4

Comment: I also tried everythin on pyinstaller official page, like using `--onedir` etc. Still same problem. Python version: 3.4

Comment: @I. A. Gerogiannis what command line options are you passing to pyinstaller?

Comment: pyinstaller --windowed --onefile app.py or pyinstaller --windowed --onedir app.py. I also tried recently using pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --noupx myapp.py, but none of them has created an executable, which runs on different pcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python3.7-64bit and PyInstaller 3.6 does the job without any errors.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my issue using `--noupx` when I use pyinstaller. [PyQt5-Python 3.4]

Example;

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --noupx --icon=app.ico myapp.py
```

Check [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly) if the codes above doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: The exact same problem. When running the executable from a different pc, gives me the fatal error, i mention above. Not "importerror" or "file not found" messages, as mentioned in the guide you sent me, but "fatal error" (i dont know if there is any similarity). Furthermore i have checked all the steps to "start clean", and it seems i have been following them correctly. Though I still get the error message. Thanks a lot for your effort and time you spent.

Comment: @I.A.Gerogiannis I put bounty on the question but... it looks like bounty point is going to the garbage...